# JavaScript - jQuery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Моя задача - загрузить содержимое селектора с другой страницы. Есть метод load() в фреймворке jQuery. Так вот, этот метод загружает селектор и его внутренности, а мне нужно загрузить лишь внутренности. Так вот и вопрос - как такое можно провернуть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос примерами, чтобы людям, которые пытаются Вам помочь, было очевидно, каких результатов Вы хотите достичь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указать правильный селектор

```
$("result").load("test.html #my_div > *")
```

Вытащит всех детей элемента с `id="my_div"` со страницы `test.html`